# Regular Expression to find CVE Matches

Tags: regex

I am pretty new to the concept of regex and so I am hoping an expert user can help me craft the right expression to find all the matches in a string.  I have a string that represents a lot of support information in it for vulnerabilities data.  In that string are a series of CVE references in the format: CVE-2015-4000.  Can anyone provide me a sample regex on finding all occurrences of that ?  obviously, the numeric part of that changes throughout the string...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Generally you should always include your previous efforts in your question, what exactly you expect to match, etc. But since I am aware of the format and this is an easy one...

```
CVE-\d{4}-\d{4,7}
```

This matches first `CVE-` then a 4-digit number for the year identifier and then a 4 to 7 digit number to identify the vulnerability as per the new standard.

See this in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/vZ7yZ0/2).

Comment: Thank you very much good sir!  It was my first ever stackoverflow question and you answered it with a working example.  I do appreciate it very much!

Comment: it doesn't work for this string "`CVE-2022–32511 | Exploit | Remote Code Execution`"

Comment: This regex is not correct due to changes in CVE format introduced in 2014 https://cve.mitre.org/cve/identifiers/syntaxchange.html - There is no limit on the number of arbitrary digits

Comment: Good answer, however this will fail in year 10'000 and more... (just joking ^^)

Comment: Your regex matches for CVE-1000-0815 or CVE-2023-0000 but these are not valid CVE numbers.

Comment: Regex doesn't pick up the text from pasting?

Answer (score 5):

If you need an exact match without any syntax or logic violations, you can try this (now fixed the flaw noted in the comments without matching CVE-YYYY-0000):

```
^CVE-(1999|2\d{3})-(?!0{4})(0\d{2}[0-9]|[1-9]\d{3,})$
```

You can run this against the test data supplied by MITRE [here](https://cve.mitre.org/cve/identifiers/tech-guidance.html#test_data) to test your code, or test it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/C5rUSo/1).

Comment: This doesn't work against valid CVEs such as CVE-1999-0520, CVE-2000-0800, CVE-2002-0510, CVE-2004-0230.

If you change it to:
```^(CVE-(1999|2\d{3})-(0\d{2}[0-9]|[1-9]\d{3,}))$``` it works :)

Comment: This will fail in year 3000+. why such a complicated approach and restriction on the date ?

Comment: @DarthCaniac : is there a reason to use `\d{2}[0-9]` instead of `\d{3}` ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac Your approach would be also syntactically valid but the correction of DarthCaniac has an edge case where CVE-2023-0000 will match, even though this is an invalid CVE. I tried to address this in my answer but forget about the ones ending with 0. About the date restriction: for me it's reasonable to assume that we'll have something better in a thousand years ;)

Answer (score 1):

I will add my two cents to the accepted answer. Incase we want to detect case insensitive  "CVE" we can following regex

```
r'(?i)\bcve\-\d{4}-\d{4,7}'
```